# Can't get input value to be updated as it's changed

Tags: javascript

I want to update the variable `searchUrl` as I change the input value. However, `input.value` adds nothing to `searchUrl`. On the other hand, if you see it on the console, `input.value` does have a different value every time it's updated, but it is not added to `searchUrl`. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let input = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox__input"))[0];
let wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&uselang=user&search=";

let searchUrl = wikiUrl + input.value;

$(".searchbox__input").on("changed keyup", function() {
    console.log(searchUrl);
    console.log(input.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="wikipedia.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="searchbox">
            <input class="searchbox__input" type="text">
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="wikipedia.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `searchUrl`  inside the event , the value of `searchUrl` is not getting updated because you're not adding the value of the input during the `changed keyup` event

```js
let input = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox__input"))[0];
let wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&uselang=user&search=";
let searchUrl


$(".searchbox__input").on("changed keyup", function() {
 searchUrl = wikiUrl + input.value;
    console.log(searchUrl);
    console.log(input.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="wikipedia.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="searchbox">
            <input class="searchbox__input" type="text">
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="wikipedia.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: oh! so simple, right? thank you for the explanation!